# C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, syntax-error

I am new to programming and teaching myself RoR. I am using http://ruby.railstutorial.org as my first guide. I thought I was doing well, then a seemingly simple issue came up that even after several reads of good post on stack related to this topic I still can't fix it. I would appreciate it if someone could kindly point out the issue/s I have within my code.

Thank you.

I am getting this error.

C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND

Here is the code I am using:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @title = @user.name
end

def new
  @user = User.new
  @title = "Sign up"
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
  sign_in @user
  flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
  redirect_to @user
else
  @title = "Sign up"
  render 'new'
 end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the indentation in your `create` method. You didn't indent anything under the `if @user.save`. I know that seems a bit off-topic, but if you had the indentation right, you'd see that the there is no `end` closing the class.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = @user.name
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @title = "Sign up"
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Sign up"
      render 'new'
    end # <= ends the if
  end # <= ends the def create
end # <= ends the class
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and feedback. I can see how greater attention to detail will help me with programming.